# $\mathbb{R},\emptyset$, and every interval $(-n,n)$ are a topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am taking a course in general topology. And I am struggling with the following exercise:

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of all real numbers. Prove that each of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is a topology.
>
> i) $\mathscr{T}$ consists of $\mathbb{R},\emptyset$, and every interval $(-n,n)$, for $n$ any positive integer.

**Definition of topology:**

1. $X,\emptyset\in\mathscr{T}$
2. If $\{x_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, so that $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}^{}x_\lambda\in\mathscr{T} $
3. If $A,A'\in\mathscr{T}$ then $A\cap A\in\mathscr{T}$

1) The first definition is checked once $\mathbb{R},\emptyset\in\mathscr{T}$

2) The second definition is the one I do not know how to tackle. It seems straight-forward to mw that the union of any $(-n,n)$ belongs in the topology. However I do not know how to write a proof about it.

**Question:**

How should I write a proof of the second axiom?

Answer (score 2):

The core of your proof ought to be that

- if $\Lambda = \{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, … \lambda_n \}$ is a non-empty finite set of (positive) integers, then

$$\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}x_{\lambda} = x_{\max \Lambda}$$

and that

- if $\Lambda$ is infinite then the union is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $\Lambda$ is infinite would it not be right to say it is containded in $\mathbb{R}$ since $n$ is positive integer?

Comment: Each element of $\Lambda$ *is* a positive integer, though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually
$$\bigcup (-n,n)=(-\max n,\max n)$$
if that the maximum exists, otherwise 
$$\bigcup (-n,n)=\mathbb R$$

Comment: Assuming that the maximum exists, and is not infinite (remember, topologies are closed with respect to *arbitrary* unions).

Comment: thank you. I am thinking about $\sup$, isn't better?

Comment: The supremum gets the job done, or do as T.Bongers has done, and divide the argument into cases.